# Chart.js line chart with area range

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'd like to add another dimension to a [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) line chart, similar to the chart below, or [this Highcharts example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange-line). I'm having difficulty understanding where I'd be able to implement such a feature, given Chart.js' myriad extension options.

[image: Line chart with area]

Ideally, I'd be able to provide a dataset with a field similar to `data` specifying the width of the line at a certain point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create new chart type from the line chart type to do this

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
Chart.defaults.stripe = Chart.helpers.clone(Chart.defaults.line);
Chart.controllers.stripe = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  draw: function(ease) {
    var result = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

    // don't render the stripes till we've finished animating
    if (!this.rendered && ease !== 1)
      return;
    this.rendered = true;


    var helpers = Chart.helpers;
    var meta = this.getMeta();
    var yScale = this.getScaleForId(meta.yAxisID);
    var yScaleZeroPixel = yScale.getPixelForValue(0);
    var widths = this.getDataset().width;
    var ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.getDataset().backgroundColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.beginPath();

    // initialize the data and bezier control points for the top of the stripe
    helpers.each(meta.data, function(point, index) {
      point._view.y += (yScale.getPixelForValue(widths[index]) - yScaleZeroPixel);
    });
    Chart.controllers.line.prototype.updateBezierControlPoints.apply(this);

    // draw the top of the stripe
    helpers.each(meta.data, function(point, index) {
      if (index === 0)
        ctx.moveTo(point._view.x, point._view.y);
      else {
        var previous = helpers.previousItem(meta.data, index);
        var next = helpers.nextItem(meta.data, index);

        Chart.elements.Line.prototype.lineToNextPoint.apply({
          _chart: {
            ctx: ctx
          }
        }, [previous, point, next, null, null])
      }
    });

    // revert the data for the top of the stripe
    // initialize the data and bezier control points for the bottom of the stripe
    helpers.each(meta.data, function(point, index) {
      point._view.y -= 2 * (yScale.getPixelForValue(widths[index]) - yScaleZeroPixel);
    });
    // we are drawing the points in the reverse direction
    meta.data.reverse();
    Chart.controllers.line.prototype.updateBezierControlPoints.apply(this);

    // draw the bottom of the stripe
    helpers.each(meta.data, function(point, index) {
      if (index === 0)
        ctx.lineTo(point._view.x, point._view.y);
      else {
        var previous = helpers.previousItem(meta.data, index);
        var next = helpers.nextItem(meta.data, index);

        Chart.elements.Line.prototype.lineToNextPoint.apply({
          _chart: {
            ctx: ctx
          }
        }, [previous, point, next, null, null])
      }

    });

    // revert the data for the bottom of the stripe
    meta.data.reverse();
    helpers.each(meta.data, function(point, index) {
      point._view.y += (yScale.getPixelForValue(widths[index]) - yScaleZeroPixel);
    });
    Chart.controllers.line.prototype.updateBezierControlPoints.apply(this);

    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

    return result;
  }
});
```

and then

```
...
data: ...,
width: [12, 4, 5, 13, 12, 2, 19],
...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/u20cfpcd/

Note:
There seems to be an intermittent problem with the bands not appearing. Commmenting out `if (!this.rendered && ease !== 1) return` seems to fix this. Thanks @ClaudeBrisson for identifying the problem and solution!

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks. Would it relatively simple to animate the area bg fill? So it fades in smoothly after the animation. Could it be done with css transition?

Comment: When I upgrade ChartJS to 2.5+ parts of the above script break eg; Chart.elements.Line.prototype.lineToNextPoint.apply(). Any chance you might help me to update them?

Comment: The provided jsfiddle seems broken, only simple lines are shown.

Comment: @ClaudeBrisson - just checked and its working in IE11 and the latest Chrome. The bands appear after the animation completes.

Comment: @potatopeelings Under chromium, from version 59 to version 65 on linux, I have to click on a dataset to see areas, otherwise only simple lines are shown.

Comment: @potatopeelings wtf?! It seems to work now. Did you change something?

Comment: @potatopeelings hum... it still happens sometimes... I guess there is a race condition somewhere.

Comment: @potatopeelings if I comment out `if (!this.rendered && ease !== 1) return` it seems to always work.

Comment: @ClaudeBrisson - thanks! I've added it to the answer. I don't remember enough of the library / code to figure out why I did that originally :-)