# ChartJS v2.6 update breaks custom line-with-area-range (stripe) chart

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js

I have created a Line-with-area-range (stripe) chart based on [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992392/chart-js-line-chart-with-area-range#answer-37112998) from @potatopeelings.

However it is based on ChartJS v2.1 and when I update to ChartJS v2.6 - necessary for other requirements (annotations) - the custom chart type breaks.

**Examples**

ChartJSv2.1 - http://jsfiddle.net/u20cfpcd/

ChartJSv2.6 - http://jsfiddle.net/cjweb/99nc8atn/

These lines break:

`Chart.elements.Line.prototype.lineToNextPoint.apply(...)`

`Chart.controllers.line.prototype.updateBezierControlPoints.apply(...)`

I think the Line prototype should now use 'draw' but I can't work it out.

Any help please? I'll buy you a Big Gulp! ;)

Comment: I added `console.log(Chart.elements.Line.prototype);` and it seems like the `lineToNextPoint` function was removed from `prototype`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out.

lineToNextPoint() became obsolete and the lineTo() helper can be used.

So...

`Chart.elements.Line.prototype.lineToNextPoint.apply({
  _chart: {
    ctx: ctx
  }
}, [previous, point, next, null, null])`

...is replaced with:

```
helpers.canvas.lineTo(ctx, previous._view, point._view);
```